# Why is `\>` allowed to produce no space whatever in math mode?

Tags: math-mode, spacing

I'm setting a complicated mix of computer code and math.  To separate the keywords from the math, `\;` was too much space and `\,` was too little.  I tried `\>` but then the space disappeared entirely!

I found the culprit in `fontmath.ltx`:

```
\thinmuskip=3mu
\medmuskip=4mu plus 2mu minus 4mu
\thickmuskip=5mu plus 5mu
```

**Why** is the medium skip allowed to disappear entirely??

Comment: Because we didn't change it and Leslie Lamport copied Donald Knuth's setting in plain TeX. So you would have to ask at the top...

Comment: @David Carlisle so, all we need to do is to get DEK to join TeX.SE ...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Don does answer his mail (about every 3 to 6 months), so it's tempting.  But I did some prowling and I think I have guessed the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Pure speculation on my part, I've now read the TeXbook, and I've learned this:

- Control sequences `\,`, `\>`, and `\;` are shorthands for skipping `\thinmuskip`, `\medmuskip`, and `\thickmuskip` respectively.
- These glue amounts are **primitive** to TeX.  Why, because they are inserted automatically between symbols in math formulas.
- The insertion is described by a table in Chapter 18 of the TeXbook.  In my edition, it's on page 170.  The key observation: `\medmuskip` is *always* used around binary operators, and it is *only* used around binary operators.  (These are symbols like $+$.)

So much is fact.  Now I'm guessing Don's intent:

- I'm guessing Don wanted some shrinkability in math formulas (God knows my own work needs it), and he put it there so that the space around a binary operator can shrink to nothing.
- I'm guessing that the parsimony and symmetry of `\,`, `\>`, and `\;` appealed to him, and that he was thinking in terms of exposing the underlying mechanism through macros.  (If you've read Don's work, you'll know that he is always aware of every bit in every word. It's terrifying.)

In conclusion, I'm guessing that the problem Don was trying to solve was not, "enable the user to insert space that is guaranteed to be thin, medium, or thick." Instead, Don must have been trying to enable the user to insert space that is exactly the same as what TeX inserts automatically.

Comment: well yes but I don't think that answers the question, even though .it's your question. Sure `\>` adds `\medmuskip` which is the space added around binop, but there is still a reasonable question why is that allowed to shrink to 0pt in plain tex?